# FIDO2: will FIDO foundation MDS 1.0 metadata statements be migrated to MDS 2.0?

Tags: fido, web-authentication, webauthn

The FIDO foundation provides with metadata web service for UAF (MDS 1.0, https://mds.fidoalliance.org/) and a new web services for FIDO2 / WebAuthn metadata (MDS 2.0, see https://fidoalliance.org/metadata/).

Metadata of some authenticators are only available in the MDS 1.0 web service, but not in the MDS 2.0 web services, such as UAF security keys.

WebAuthn is however meant to be retro-compatible with UAF keys. Will the metadata of these authenticators be eventually migrated to the MDS 2.0 web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. According to [this tweet from a project member](https://twitter.com/herrjemand/status/1131806655446966276) (triggered by your question!), the FIDO projects are actively working on migrating MDS metadata to MDS2.